# Registering a device with an application based on MAC address

Tags: web-applications, lan, mac-address, arp

I am trying to build an application that runs on a local server, which can be accessed by smart phone devices connecting to it through a router (say placed at the security gates). It is an in-campus check-in/check-out local application, and not meant to be accessed by clients over the internet.

Now I want to register each smartphone device uniquely with the web-application so that there are no extra details to be fed in, or no login be required each time during check-in or check-out. And my approach would be to register each device based on its MAC address.

Will I be able to retrieve the MAC address of any device on the network connected to the application? I would prefer PHP.

```
exec('arp '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$user_mac);
```

Will the arp command be able to retrieve addresses on this network? Also, are there better ways to identify devices uniquely, and permanently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC addresses are not visible across segments, you need to have no routers between you and your client to be able to get its MAC address from ARP.

Comment: Do you see an alternative I could use? I could develop a phone application that keeps a user always logged in, but a web-application would help me write device-independent code.

Comment: Are you concerned with attacks (i.e. somebody impersonating someone else, or concealing their identity in some other manner), or do you just want to be able to tell devices apart and consider it a "friendly" environment? You could simply set a long-lived identification cookie or store an identifier in local storage (though I have no idea how supported LS is on mobile devices). Or, if you could work together with your campus DHCP server, it would be possible to implement a way to ask it directly for the MAC address associated with a leased IP address.

Comment: I just want to be able to tell devices apart in a "friendly" environment. Save the time of entering credentials to checkin. A session might just get cleared with browser history.